# Using a controller to scrape own youtube video descriptions for outdated urls

Tags: controllers, json

Our website issues approximately twenty 503 errors a day from outdated URLs located on various videos on our YouTube channel.  We have a large number of videos and it is completely unfeasible to manually search through them all. Below is some code that I have quickly constructed to access YouTube video descriptions via their native feed api.  It encodes information about videos in an (optionally) JSON format.  Is it feasible to scrape this information using a magento controller?  Or should I deploy this elsewhere?

Below is a summary of action this algorithm takes:

I have all the hashed key values stored in a text file called 'youtube_videos_only_hash.txt.  It gets these hash values and puts them into an array.  It then iterates over this array and  retrieves json descriptions of each page.  It then examines these descriptions for outdated URLs.  If an outdated URL is found It will then append the hashes to a regular YouTube URL and log these newly constructed URLs for manual examination.

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $hashes = explode("\n", file_get_contents('youtube_videos_only_hash.txt'));
    $hashes = array_unique($hashes);
    $description = array();
    $outdatedURLs = array();
    foreach ($hashes as $hash) {
        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $hash . '?v=2alt=json&prettyprint=true'));
        $description[] = $json->data->description;
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($hashes); $i++) {
        if (strpos($description[i], 'placeholder') !== false) {
            $outdatedURLs[] = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $hashes[i];
        }
    }
    foreach ($outdatedURLs as $outdatedURL) {
        Mage::log($outdatedURL, null, 'outdatedURLs.log', true);
    }
}
```

Final solution is trimmed down to this:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $hashes = explode("\n", file_get_contents('youtube_videos_only_hash.txt'));
    $hashes = array_unique($hashes);
    foreach ($hashes as $hash) {
        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $hash . '?v=2&alt=json'), true);
        $cat = $json['entry']['media$group']['media$description']['$t'];
        if ((strpos($cat, 'pgsize')) !== false || (strpos($cat, 'bit.ly') !== false)) {
            $outdatedURL = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $hash;
            Mage::log($outdatedURL, null, 'outdatedURLs.log', true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a one off issue that does not utilize any of magento core functionality except (log) then you could either create a simple php script (and create your only logging functionality) or create a custom module in magento. Also you could achieve the same thing using only one loop

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $hashes = explode("\n", file_get_contents('youtube_videos_only_hash.txt'));
    $hashes = array_unique($hashes);

    foreach ($hashes as $hash) {
        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $hash . '?v=2&alt=json'), true)
        if (strpos($json['entry']['media$group']['media$description']['$t'], 'placeholder') !== false){       
            $outdatedURL = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $hash;
            Mage::log($outdatedURL, null, 'outdatedURLs.log', true);
        }
    }
}
```

You may want to do some error checking

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably attempt to just create a custom module and and access the method that way.  I was basically asking about the technical feasibility of using a magento controller to scrape other websites.  It seems like it would work, right?

Comment: The '$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $hash . '?v=2alt=json'))' section doesn't work as expected, any suggestion as to a replacement for getting the contents of a website?

Comment: What issue are you having? `...$hash . '?v=2alt=json` should be `...$hash . '?v=2&alt=json` (note the '&' between 2 and alt

Comment: ah yes, i've fixed that.  However, I do not log anything when I attempt to long the $json variable.  When I attempt to log the associated file_get_contents of the website the data structure is present.

Comment: I just test it and it work so double check if `json_decode` is supported see http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php or try Mage::helper('core')->jsonDecode(..)

Comment: Thanks, got it to work.  I'll mess around with accessing the description of $json a bit.  I'll accept your answer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251007/getting-title-description-and-number-of-views-of-a-youtube-video

Comment: Mage::log($json['entry']['media$group']['media$description']['$t'], null, 'outdatedURLs.log', true);
 Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: note the  json_decode(..., true)

Comment: you sir, are both a gentleman and a scholar.